# Error when using the sqlite3 module in electron

Tags: windows-8, javascript, node.js, web-development

An error occurs when trying to use the NPM package sqlite3 in Electron. What can I do to get electron-builder to run? Or what can I do to use sqlite3 in electron ?

My development environment is

- windows 8.1 x64
- node version v10.15.3
- npm version 6.4.1.

My package.json file looks like this:
[image: my package.json file]

As an example the following project files:

**index.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3")

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

After typing the command `npm start` into the cmd terminal, the following error message appears:

[image: error after run electron]

As a result, I found the following problem solution on Stack Overflow:
[How to use sqlite3 module with electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504307/how-to-use-sqlite3-module-with-electron#answer-41230765)

Then I made the above changes to my package.json file. After executing the command `npm run postinstall` in the terminal the following error message appears

```
λ npm run postinstall

> xxx@0.1.0 postinstall C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx
> electron-builder install-app-deps

Configuring yargs through package.json is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use the JS API instead.
Configuring yargs through package.json is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, please use the JS API instead.
  • electron-builder version=20.39.0
  • rebuilding native production dependencies platform=win32 arch=x64
Error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe exited with code 1
Output:

> sqlite3@4.0.6 install C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.1-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.1-win32-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=electron-v4.1' (1)

Error output:
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.0.6/electron-v4.1-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.0.6 and electron@4.1.3 (electron-v4.1 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v4.1-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v4.1-win32-x64" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=electron-v4.1"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.1-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.1-win32-x64 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=electron-v4.1' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.0.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-04T17_19_09_963Z-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.childProcess.once.code (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:244:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
From previous event:
    at _rebuild (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\util\yarn.ts:179:5)
    at rebuild (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out\util\yarn.js:163:19)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\util\yarn.ts:20:11
From previous event:
    at _installOrRebuild (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out\util\yarn.js:71:28)
    at installOrRebuild (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\app-builder-lib\out\util\yarn.js:55:28)
    at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\electron-builder\src\cli\install-app-deps.ts:56:9
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
From previous event:
    at _installAppDeps (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\electron-builder\out\cli\install-app-deps.js:176:26)
    at installAppDeps (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\electron-builder\out\cli\install-app-deps.js:144:26)
    at then (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\node_modules\electron-builder\src\cli\cli.ts:46:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xxx@0.1.0 postinstall: `electron-builder install-app-deps`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xxx@0.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-04T17_19_10_020Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you fixed it yet,
But as a workaround I downgraded to electron 4.0.0 and then it found the correct sqlite binaries

Comment: I just initialized a new project and installed electron in version 4.0.0 and the latest version of sqlite3. The same error still appears in the console: "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\sqlitetest\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.0-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'"".